# LEGv8 Extention with N-bit adder

Tags: arm, computer-science, cpu-architecture

If we extend the legv8 design to add an N-bit comparator in order to find min/max of a number from a given array, would it be better than having to find out the min/max with the current convention through subtraction and loop? Basically, we have a question which allows us to extend the current legv8 design in order to compute the min/max more efficiently. So in order to do that, I've thought about adding an n-bit comparator and then modifying the data paths and control signals. Would there be any better way to go around this problem or am i on the right track?

Comment: Huh?  LEGv8 can already implement `cmp` by running `subs` with `xzr` as the destination.  https://montcs.bloomu.edu/Information/ARMv8/legv8-green-card.compressed.pdf  cmp is just sub that sets flags but discards the integer result.

Comment: Or do you mean you want to implement a `min  dst, src1, src2` instruction that does the full min without needing cmp/bgt or whatever.  ARM [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) has this, packed min of elements in a 16-byte vector, letting you loop over an array 16 bytes at a time.  e.g. `smin v1.4S, v1.4S, v2.4S` to do packed min of `int32x4_t`.  e.g. you can see GCC using it to auto-vectorize a loop: https://godbolt.org/z/3G1ET4.  Or clang using `ldp` to load 2x 16 bytes at a time: https://godbolt.org/z/E1s8Px.  Yes, SIMD is a useful thing.